# Microsoft Access - how change the label of the aggregate function "Totals" in its row

Tags: function, ms-access, label, aggregate

I've been trying to do some exercises from a book teaching on how to use MS Access (in my case 2016 version is utilized).

In one of the sections, an example is given on how to perform a quick calculation using the aggregate function by clicking the "Totals" buttons from the Record group in the HOME tab, all this on a query displayed in Datasheet View with some records present. The Query in question:
[image: Query using the Average aggregate function]

Now, in this query I (want to only) calculate/use the "Average" function over the "DonationValue" field values, which works.

The problem is, that the label at the beginning of the row says "Total", and I cannot seem to be able change it to say something else:
[image: Total label]

Even when I click over the "None" option from the falling options above, the label just remains saying "Total" (I don't know what to expect).

My question is, is there any way possible to change this label to say "Average" instead of "Total", so it is in a "logical conjunction" with the average aggregate function used further along the row? And how?

Workarounds are also welcome.

Cheers,
G.M.

Comment: Not in table/query or form in Datasheet mode. Use a form in Continuous mode and put the calc in a textbox with its own label. Users should not interact with tables and queries so this should not be important anyway. Design your app to use forms and reports for user interaction.

Comment: @G.M. Kindly click on checkmark next to answer if the solution was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a query using Union function like below:

```
SELECT PatronID, FirstName, LastName, DonationValue  from Donation

Union 

Select 'Average',null, null, Round(avg(DonationValue),2)  from Donation
```

[image]

Note: When the query is attached to datasheet the form would be read-only